# How to connect arduino with visual studion windows form

Tags: button

I have a game in visual studion windows form application
How can an arduino push button work as same as the wfa button ?
Thanks

Comment: First time using arduino how to connect it to c# code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# provides a SerialPort class that you can use to interface with the Arduino.
You can open the port like this:

```
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;

private string loadAvailablePorts()
{
    ManagementScope connectionScope = new ManagementScope();
    SelectQuery serialQuery = new SelectQuery("SELECT * FROM Win32_SerialPort");
    ManagementObjectSearcher searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher(connectionScope, serialQuery);

    try
    {
        foreach (ManagementObject item in searcher.Get())
        {
            string desc = item["Description"].ToString();
            string deviceId = item["DeviceID"].ToString();

            if (desc.Contains("Arduino"))
            {
                return deviceId;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (ManagementException ex)
    {
        Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }

    return null;
}

private bool openSerialPort()
{
    try
    {
        serialPort1 = new SerialPort(loadAvailablePorts());
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        return false;
    }

    if (serialPort1 != null)
    {
        serialPort1.BaudRate = 9600;
        serialPort1.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(dataReceived);

        try
        {
            serialPort1.Open();
        }
        catch(UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
        catch(IOException ex)
        {
            Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Notice the DataReceived event handler.  You can use that to trigger your button presses.  In your Arduino code you will need to write some output to the serial port that shows you clicked the button, which you can then detect in your C# code.  For my purposes, I only read data from sensors attached to the Arduino, so for me its a matter of parsing strings written using Serial.println(...), but for your button press maybe you will use digitalWrite.  I don't have experience with Arduino buttons but it should not be hard to detect the click in C# one way or another.

In C#, you need to write a method to programmatically click the button, which you can do in the DataReceived event handler.

```
private void dataReceived(object sender, System.IO.Ports.SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
{
    string capturedText = string.Empty;

    try
    {
        capturedText = serialPort1.ReadLine();
    }
    catch (InvalidOperationException ex)
    {
        Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }
    catch (IOException ex)
    {
        Util.Log(ex.Message + "\n" + ex.StackTrace);
    }

    if (capturedText.Contains("1"))
    {
        myButton.PerformClick();
    }
}
```

Your Arduino code might look something like this example from https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button:

```
// constants won't change. They're used here to
// set pin numbers:
const int buttonPin = 2;     // the number of the pushbutton pin

// variables will change:
int buttonState = 0;         // variable for reading the pushbutton status

void setup() {
    // initialize the pushbutton pin as an input:
    pinMode(buttonPin, INPUT);
}

void loop() {
    // read the state of the pushbutton value:
    buttonState = digitalRead(buttonPin);

    // check if the pushbutton is pressed.
    // if it is, the buttonState is HIGH:
    if (buttonState == HIGH) {
        Serial.println("1");
    } else {
        Serial.println("0")
    }
}
```

I hope this helps.  This should be enough to get your example working or at least get you on the right path.

Comment: I need help with arduino code first time using it:(

Comment: For your button press it should be pretty simple.  Here is example from [https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Button).